# UIGestureRecognizer on Map results on Map cannot be moved?

Tags: ios, objective-c, baidu-map

I am trying to detect when user starts and stops dragging on mapview with this following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRec = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didDragMap:)];
    [panRec setDelegate:self];
    [_mapView addGestureRecognizer:panRec];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}

- (void)didDragMap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        NSLog(@"drag ended");
    }
}
```

However, the map seem doesn't move at all while the UIGestureRecognizer gives me what I want.

What could be wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, I had added your gesture recognizer and work just fine

Comment: @ReinierMelian sorry I think this is the Baidu (which is I use for this app) map's issue. I thought Baidu has quite same implementation with MKMapView, but just realized that Baidu has this issue, while in MKMapView not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I only need to add this

```
panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Not sure is it Baidu Map bug or not since MKMapView works fine without that option.